# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in xcode (c++)

Tags: c++

I've got a problem with one project in c++. Everything was compiling and working great, and then I've received this message - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

And also:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN4Plaz10zmienSlowoENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projekt2-bscwaavexcuiwpcjixrepxglqkww/Build/Intermediates/projekt2.build/Debug/projekt2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bezogonowe.o
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projekt2-bscwaavexcuiwpcjixrepxglqkww/Build/Intermediates/projekt2.build/Debug/projekt2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/beznogie.o
```

duplicate symbol __ZN4Plaz10zmienSlowoENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projekt2-bscwaavexcuiwpcjixrepxglqkww/Build/Intermediates/projekt2.build/Debug/projekt2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bezogonowe.o
    /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projekt2-bscwaavexcuiwpcjixrepxglqkww/Build/Intermediates/projekt2.build/Debug/projekt2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/plaz.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I've read that it can be a problem connected with duplicated main files, but I could not find how to make it work. There are my files.

[image]

Comment: Could it be an include file declaring a variable and being included by both bezogonowe.cpp and beznogie.cpp?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you refering to main? In main I've got only
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "plaz.h"

Comment: Not main... I was just wondering if the two cpp files includes the same h file and that h file had something like `string x` or similar. I think that would cause a duplicate symbol.

Comment: The solution was really simple - I was trying to reach the int that was in different class. Thanks for help!